# Cascading parameters - are you able to skip a parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Thank you to the previous posters, I've had to adapt the report  a bit since I posted the initial question, so this is an edit.

I'm trying to create a report using cascading parameters.  I've added an 'All' option into the 'LocalAuthority' parameter but get no values back when it moves on to the @ward parameter.
[image]

This is how the parameter criteria is set in my 'main data' stored procedure

```
WHERE [county] = @county

            AND [LocalAuthority] = @LocalAuthority 

                     AND CHARINDEX  (','+Ward+',', ','+@Ward+',') > 0
```

This is a partial view of my stored procedure for LocalAuthority

```
 SELECT * FROM 

         (

                  select distinct


                     LocalAuthority,
                     county               
                     from tableA 



                    where [county] like 'essex'


                union all 


                select distinct

                    LocalAuthority,
                    county             
                    from tableA 



                  where county like 'kent' 


                union all

                    select distinct

                       'All' as LocalAuthority,
                       'CountyWide' as county      

                      from tableA 

                    )a

WHERE 

    LocalAuthority = @LocalAuthority
```

Comment: You can set the default value of `@LocalAuthority` to the same the dataset you are using in available values. So if you don't select any value in `@LocalAuthority` by default it will run with all values defined in your dataset.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta  Does that not only work for multi value parameters?  From the question and mention of an `All` option being added to `@City` it would suggest that these are single valued.

Comment: One thing you can do is create an additional parameter and set it to be hidden, to check if `@City = "All"` if so return nothing to your query otherwise return the `@LocalAuthority` selection.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta  Per my answer below, you just need to set the default to a value that can only mean "Ignore this parameter" which will never be returned in the data driven parameter value list.  When the default value is not present in the list, the user needs to select one that is, which means the user only has to interact with the `@LocalAuthority` parameter when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using single valued parameters, I would suggest populating your parameters with a dataset and having that dataset simply check for an `All` in the `@City` parameter and return one value such as `Ignore` if `All` is selected.  In your main dataset you then return all LAs when `IGNORE` is returned using a `case` statement.

You can use something similar to the query below to specify your `@LocalAuthority` value list and set the default value to `IGNORE` which will populate if available and require user selection from the list of LAs if not.  This way you do not need user interaction if you are ignoring your LAs:

```
declare @City nvarchar(50) = 'a';

declare @LAs table (LA nvarchar(50));
insert into @LAs values
 ('Birmingham')
,('Grenwich')
,('Exeter')


select distinct case when @City = 'All'
                    then 'IGNORE'
                    else LA
                    end as LocalAuthorities
from @LAs


set @City = 'All';

select distinct case when @City = 'All'
                    then 'IGNORE'
                    else LA
                    end as LocalAuthorities
from @LAs
```